# When you combine two models in Keras, how can you initialize only the weight of one model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm going to combine the two models and run the machine learning.

1. LSTM layer for time series data learning
2. Fully connected layer connected by Dense

Figure-wise, it is roughly similar to the following: Combining these two models into FC was a success.

Of these values, LSTM layer side has the weight saved.

My objective is to initialize the weights on the LSTM model side before the model combination into the pre-saved weight values.
How can weights on the side of the LSTM model be initialized to the weight values saved and combined with FC layers?

The first code is error-free, and the second code is modified to initialize only the weights on the side of the LSTM model.

```py
inputA = Input(shape=(7,1))
inputB = Input(shape=(1,))

#Part 1 : LSTM
x = LSTM(20, activation="linear")(inputA)
x = Dense(10, activation="linear")(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)

#Part 2 : FC
y = Dense(10, activation="relu")(inputB)
y = Dense(1)(y)

#Part 3 : Concatenate
combined = concatenate([x, y])

z = Dense(2, activation="linear")(combined)
z = Dense(10, activation="linear")(z)
z = Dense(1, activation="linear")(z)

model = Model(inputs=[inputA,inputB] ,outputs=z)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

```py
#Part 1 : LSTM, I want to update the weight of this model.
LSTM_model = Sequential()
LSTM_model.add(LSTM(10,input_shape=(7,1),inner_activation="linear"))
LSTM_model.add(Dense(10))
LSTM_model.add(Dense(1))
LSTM_model.load_weights(weight)

#Part 2 : FC
y = Dense(10, activation="relu")(inputB)
y = Dense(1)(y)

#Part 3 : Concatenate
combined = concatenate([LSTM_model, y])

z = Dense(2, activation="linear")(combined)
z = Dense(10, activation="linear")(z)
z = Dense(1, activation="linear")(z)

model = Model(inputs=[inputA,inputB] ,outputs=z)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

Comment: What do you need to do that the code doesn't do?

Comment: Sorry, the code in the text is already an error. The [LSTM_model] section results in an error.

Comment: Can you add the error

Comment: Instead of saving just the weights you could save and load the whole LSTM model [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

Comment: I don't have an environment to run the program in now, so we'll update it as soon as we can.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment..! I know how to save a model. Previously, the LSTM model was saved using that method, but it was difficult to concatenate with the FC model.